# A Neo4j container (docker) with initial data in it

Tags: docker, neo4j

Other database dockers that I've worked with (like Postgres) have a mechanism to import some initial data into their empty instance once the container starts for the first time. This is usually in form of putting your SQL files in a specific folder.

I need to do the same for Neo4j. I want to compose a Neo4j docker image with some data in it. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486424/create-custom-neo4j-docker-image-with-intial-data-from-cypher-file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be achieved...
There are 2 requirements:

1. set initial password, which could be achieved using `bin/neo4j-admin set-initial-password <password>` and then
2. import data from file in cypher format `cat import/data.cypher | NEO4J_USERNAME=neo4j NEO4J_PASSWORD=${NEO4J_PASSWD} bin/cypher-shell --fail-fast`

Sample `Dockerfile` may look like this

```
FROM neo4j:3.2

ENV NEO4J_PASSWD neo4jadmin
ENV NEO4J_AUTH neo4j/${NEO4J_PASSWD}

COPY data.cypher /var/lib/neo4j/import/

VOLUME /data

CMD bin/neo4j-admin set-initial-password ${NEO4J_PASSWD} || true && \
    bin/neo4j start && sleep 5 && \
    for f in import/*; do \
      [ -f "$f" ] || continue; \
      cat "$f" | NEO4J_USERNAME=neo4j NEO4J_PASSWORD=${NEO4J_PASSWD} bin/cypher-shell --fail-fast && rm "$f"; \
    done && \
    tail -f logs/neo4j.log
```

Building image `sudo docker build -t neo4j-3.1:loaddata .`

And running container `docker run -it --rm --name neo4jtest neo4j-3.1:loaddata`

Comment: Thanks, but one thing your Dockerfile does not consider is that the data.cypher should be deleted (or moved) after it is worked out so the second time the container starts, it won't make duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only problem I've still got with this is the `sleep 5` part. I've been trying to use the `bin/neo4j status`  to determine if the neo4j is running or not. But even though it is running, the mentioned command says that it is not! Any comments?

Comment: You sir (@hlihovac) are a god! I've been trying to figure this out for months! :D

Answer (score 0):

#### example of docker-compose for Neo4j

```
version: '3'
services:
  # ...

  neo4j:
    image: 'neo4j:4.1'
    ports:
      - '7474:7474'
      - '7687:7687'
    volumes:
      - '$HOME/data:/data'
      - '$HOME/logs:/logs'
      - '$HOME/import:/var/lib/neo4j/import'
      - '$HOME/conf:/var/lib/neo4j/conf'
    environment:
      NEO4J_AUTH : 'neo4j/your_password'
    # ...
```