# How can I run cypher scripts on startup of a neo4j docker container?

Tags: bash, docker, neo4j, docker-compose

### Background

I previously had neo4j installed on Windows and a PowerShell script to run some migrations. The DB is recreated every time from these migration scripts & some CSVs in the import folder. A .NET WebAPI talks to the neo4j db.

### Goal

I decided to Dockerize this setup so that I can collaborate cross-platform with folks and they don't have to directly install / configure neo4j.

I've got most of the neo4j docker container set up -- volumes, appropriate files copied, etc. and it starts up.

### Problem

No matter what, I can't seem to find a good way to insert or execute a script that will loop through the folder and execute the cypher queries. I know this will probably have to be a bash script that uses the neo4j CLI and I'm fine with that, but I can't find a good spot to make it happen.

### What I've tried

- the `EXTENSION_SCRIPT` env variable. That executes way too early in the process.
- Using my own `ENTRYPOINT` -- discovered that this appears to supersede the neo4j container's entrypoint
- Using my own `CMD` -- similarly, this appears to supersede
- Moving from `docker-compose` to `dockerfile` and copying the neo4j entrypoint file to modify it. This appears to run into an issue with an error `invalid optionn/bash: -` that I'm in the process of researching, but this is my first go of things.

### Question

How can I run one or more cypher queries after Neo4j is started? Is there a provision in either neo4j or docker to allow for this? I haven't been able to find any leads in the documentation.

Or, is this really not the recommended way to go? Should I be running these migrations on demand by entering the container and running a bash script manually that works with the CLI?

### The Scripts

Dockerfile:

```
FROM neo4j:3.3.1

COPY ./data/import/migrations/scripts /scripts

ENV NEO4J_AUTH=none

ENTRYPOINT ["/scripts/docker-neo4j-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["neo4j"]
```

Relevant snippet from `docker-compose`:

```
  neo4j:
    container_name: 'app-db'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DOCKERFILE_DB
    volumes:
      - ./data/CSVs:/import
      - ./data/import/migrations:/import/migrations
    ports: 
      - "7687:7687" # bolt protocol
      - "7474:7474" # http protocol
      - "7473:7473" # https protocol
    networks:
      - app-network
```

Comment: FYI I'm currently pursuing the strategy of using the entrypoint of my API to seed the DB. Well see how that works out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Neo4j container (docker) with initial data in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44355512/a-neo4j-container-docker-with-initial-data-in-it)

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, where I wanted to create some indexes at startup, and was able to resolve it based on the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) to create a wrapper script, and an indexes script that just sleeps until neo4j is back up, like so:

Dockerfile

```
FROM neo4j:latest

ENV NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/password

RUN apk add --no-cache --quiet procps

COPY create-indexes.sh create-indexes.sh
COPY wrapper.sh wrapper.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./wrapper.sh"]
```

wrapper.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# turn on bash's job control
set -m

# Start the primary process and put it in the background
/docker-entrypoint.sh neo4j &

# Start the helper process
./create-indexes.sh

# the my_helper_process might need to know how to wait on the
# primary process to start before it does its work and returns


# now we bring the primary process back into the foreground
# and leave it there
fg %1
```

create-indexes.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

until cypher-shell -u neo4j -p shaun123 'CREATE INDEX ON :Page(url);'
do
  echo "create page index failed, sleeping"
  sleep 10
done

until cypher-shell -u neo4j -p shaun123 'CREATE INDEX ON :Visited(url);'
do
  echo "create visited index failed, sleeping"
  sleep 10
done

until cypher-shell -u neo4j -p shaun123 'CREATE INDEX ON :Anchor(url);'
do
  echo "create anchor index failed, sleeping"
  sleep 10
done
```

I also opened this as an issue [here](https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j/issues/166), which I've copied my answer into and since closed.

Answer (score 3):

Realized I'd solved this problem -- sort of -- and wanted to post my current working solution here. Not going to mark my own answer as the solution as I believe another solution here is also viable and I don't want to be taking full credit.

The overall components are:

- A docker-compose file with an environment variable of whether to run migrations and how long to wait
- A `Dockerfile` for my WebAPI project that includes the Neo4j client
- A bash entrypoint script to run the migrations

#### The docker-compose file

Sets up neo4j and the environment variables on the API project.

```
version: '3'

services: # these are all the services that a docker app uses

  api: # this is the name of the service we're creating; it's chosen by us. Here, we're calling it "api".
    container_name: 'redacted-api' # this is the name of the container to us
    depends_on:
      - neo4j
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DOCKERFILE_API
    environment:
      - SECONDS_PAUSE_BEFORE_MIGRATION=15
      - RUN_MIGRATIONS=true
    ports:
    - "5000:10901"
    networks:
      - app-network # this is a docker feature to allow you to place your various services within a virtual network so they can talk to each other. Note all the services we define here use the "app-network" network.
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:3.3.1-enterprise
    container_name: 'redacted-db'
    environment: 
      - NEO4J_AUTH=none
      - NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=apoc.*
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
    volumes:
      - ./data/db-files:/data
      - ./data/CSVs:/import
      - ./data/import/migrations:/import/migrations
      - ./data/plugins:/plugins
    ports: 
      #TODO: Remove these so that the API can get to them but not the host? (security)
      - "7687:7687" # bolt protocol
      - "7474:7474" # http protocol
      - "7473:7473" # https protocol
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

#### The API Dockerfile

Installs the `cypher-shell` neo4j utility on the container that my WebAPI is installed in:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk

# Add the neo4j repo to the packages list
RUN wget -O - https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | apt-key add -
RUN echo 'deb http://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/' | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neo4j.list

# Grab the packages list & install neo4j
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
cypher-shell

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/src/Redacted.API

RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 10901/tcp

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

#### The Entrypoint Script

This, run on the Web API's container, cycles through any cypher queries in a migrations folder and executes them against the Neo4j container.

```sh
#!/bin/bash          


if [ "$RUN_MIGRATIONS" = "true" ] ; then
    echo "Pausing for $SECONDS_PAUSE_BEFORE_MIGRATION seconds to let Neo4j warm up"
    sleep $SECONDS_PAUSE_BEFORE_MIGRATION

    echo "Running migrations"
    for filename in /app/data/import/migrations/*.cypher; do
        echo "Attempting to run cypher: $filename" 
        contents=$( cat $filename )
        cypher-shell -a bolt://redacted-db:7687 "$contents"
    done
else
    echo "Skipping migrations because RUN_MIGRATIONS was not set to true."
fi

echo "Starting the .NET WebAPI"
dotnet run
```

#### The End Result

- The DB container starts up first
- The API depends on Neo4j, so it waits for that container to start up for the configured amount of time
- The API then runs all the migrations

#### Further Steps

I ended up having to set this aside for a bit, but the next steps for me would be to figure out how to get that Dockerfile / migrations / entrypoint entirely in the Neo4j container, which I think I could have done with a little more fussing had I not arrived at this approach which worked well enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

I created a docker image that can be reused with the refactored version of the wrappers found here and in the github issue https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j/issues/166.

## image `marcellodesales/neo4j-with-cypher-seed`

- The Docker image is at https://github.com/marcellodesales/neo4j-with-cypher-seed-docker.
- Using the protocol `bolt://` to seed data

  - `cypher-shell -f FILE` does not work

## Cyphers

- Any file with cypher content say `interviews.cql`

```
CREATE (facebook:Company {name:'Facebook'})

CREATE (clement:Candidate {name:'Clement'})
CREATE (antoine:Candidate {name:'Antoine'})
CREATE (simon:Candidate {name:'Simon'})
```

## Docker Image

- Mount the cyphers file into the volume `/cyphers`

## Profit

- Get the server loaded with the cyphers

```
docker run --rm -ti  \
   -e "NEO4J_AUTH=none" \
   -p "7474:7474" -p "7687:7687" \
   -v $(pwd)/cypher_query.cql:/cyphers/interviews.cql \
   marcellodesales/neo4j-with-cypher-seed
```

- The result is as follows

```
$ docker run --rm -ti  \
   -e "NEO4J_AUTH=none" \
   -p "7474:7474" -p "7687:7687" \
   -v $(pwd)/cypher_query.cql:/cyphers/interviews.cql \
   marcellodesales/neo4j-with-cypher-seed
2020-09-27 16:54:00:486+0000 INFO  Wrapper: Waiting until neo4j stats at :7474 ...
Directories in use:
  home:         /var/lib/neo4j
  config:       /var/lib/neo4j/conf
  logs:         /logs
  plugins:      /var/lib/neo4j/plugins
  import:       /var/lib/neo4j/import
  data:         /var/lib/neo4j/data
  certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
  run:          /var/lib/neo4j/run
Starting Neo4j.
2020-09-27 16:54:01.394+0000 INFO  Starting...
2020-09-27 16:54:03.064+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.1.2 ========
2020-09-27 16:54:04.332+0000 INFO  Initializing system graph model for component 'security-users' with version -1 and status UNINITIALIZED
2020-09-27 16:54:04.337+0000 INFO  Setting up initial user from defaults: neo4j
2020-09-27 16:54:04.338+0000 INFO  Creating new user 'neo4j' (passwordChangeRequired=true, suspended=false)
2020-09-27 16:54:04.345+0000 INFO  Setting version for 'security-users' to 2
2020-09-27 16:54:04.349+0000 INFO  After initialization of system graph model component 'security-users' have version 2 and status CURRENT
2020-09-27 16:54:04.354+0000 INFO  Performing postInitialization step for component 'security-users' with version 2 and status CURRENT
2020-09-27 16:54:04.513+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
2020-09-27 16:54:05.410+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2020-09-27 16:54:05.411+0000 INFO  Started.
2020-09-27 16:54:05:619+0000 INFO  Wrapper: Deleting all relations
2020-09-27 16:54:08:274+0000 INFO  Wrapper: Wrapper: Loading cyphers from '/cyphers'
2020-09-27 16:54:08:275+0000 INFO  Wrapper: Running cypher /cyphers/interviews.cql
0 rows available after 330 ms, consumed after another 0 ms
Added 17 nodes, Created 17 relationships, Set 34 properties, Added 17 labels
2020-09-27 16:54:09:695+0000 INFO  Wrapper: Finished loading all cyphers from '/cyphers'
2020-09-27 16:54:10:842+0000 INFO  Wrapper: Wrapper: Changes count 17
/docker-entrypoint.sh neo4j
```

[image]

Comment: @SeanKilleen Glad you liked it... I spent several hours trying to understand what was causing the errors until I reviewed your wrapper implementation... I had opened ticket https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j/issues/275 the the bugs found when using the cyper_shell directly with -F file.. In this case, Thank you for putting the first ideas up!