# Execute commands at the start of neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Neo4j from a docker, the image of Neo4j is: **Community neo4j: 3.3.4**, when the container is created I need to execute a script to create the commands I need.

I need that my server has these contrains:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Contact) ASSERT c.email IS UNIQUE
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Contact) ASSERT exists(c.firstName) 
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Contact) ASSERT exists(c.lastName)
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Contact) ASSERT exists(c.email)
```

but now I have to add them manually, and I need that when the container is built, the contrains are automatically added.

I have looked for how to do it but I have no idea, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Neo4j container (docker) with initial data in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44355512/a-neo4j-container-docker-with-initial-data-in-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create constrains.cypher

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Person) ASSERT c.email IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Person) ASSERT c.uuid IS UNIQUE;
```

and execute

```
cat /var/lib/neo4j/conf/constrains.cypher | bin/cypher-shell -u user -p Pass
```